# How to pass variables from .gitlab.ci.yml to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, variables, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

How can I pass one variables value from `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `Dockerfile`?

e.g.
The ***.gitlab-ci.yml*** contains:

```
variables:
  var1: ex_variable_1
  var2: ex_variable_1

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sudo docker build . -t ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}
                          --build-arg var1
                          --build-arg var2
    - sudo docker run -dit --name ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG} --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}:latest
```

The ***Dockefile*** contains:

```
FROM centos:6.9

ENV var1 ${var1}
ENV var2 ${var2}

RUN echo "Print var1 $var1"
RUN echo "Print var2 $var2
```

So what I want is to pass **var1** and **var2** from `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @ErikMD and Rekovni your options aren't working :|

Comment: Can you give more details than just "this doesn't work"? Did you add the `ARG` instruction in your Dockerfile as suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64266911/9164010)? what is the observed outcome?

Comment: OK, I do several additional tests and it seems **because of sudo** (which does not export the environment "as is" across the privilege elevation), `--build-arg var1` won't work, but `--build-arg var1="$var1"` should (unless you just remove `sudo`, because in a GitLab CI context, **you are already root**). I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @ErikMD thanks a lot, man. After I have put `--build-arg var1=$var1` in running docker command and `ARG var1` & `ENV var1 $var1`  in Dockerfile the variable can be accessed in the Docker file and in other files. Please Update the answer and your answer will be a solution for the issue!

Comment: OK great! but my answer should already be up-to-date… by the way, I added a remark telling that the command `ENV var1 $var1` (or `ENV var1=$var1`, this is the same) is really optional: you don't need this command to be able to use `$var1` within the Dockerfile. You only need it if you reuse the variable at runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To pass environment variables from `.gitlab-ci.yml` to an image or container:

- at build time (if the variable is used by the Dockerfile):

  - use the [`docker build --build-arg` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg): `docker build --build-arg var1="$var1"`
  - **and** change your Dockerfile like this:

    ```
      FROM centos:6.9
      ARG var1
      ARG var2

      RUN echo "Print var1 $var1"
      RUN echo "Print var2 $var2

      # The following is optional − only useful if you want to
      # keep the environment variables at runtime (docker run)
      ENV var1=${var1}
      ENV var2=${var2}
    ```

    Note: [the `ARG` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) can also take a default value:

    ```
      ARG var1="default value if var1 was not passed using --build-arg"
    ```
- at runtime (if the variable is used by the container, i.e., by the `ENTRYPOINT / CMD`-specified program):

  - use the [`docker run -e` CLI option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file): `docker run -e var1="$var1"`.